# PHP/Regex: Capture all matches for repetitive named recursion

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-group

I have the following regex:

```
\(                                          (?# Expression start)
  (?<optgroup_start>\()                  (?# Parameter group start)
    (?<parameter_set>(?:\[(?:[a-z0-9]+)\],*\s*)+) (?# Parameters, subject to recursion)
  (?<optgroup_end>\))                                (?# Parameter group end)
  ,*\s*
  (?:                                  (?# Options group start)
    "(?<options_scalar>.*)"      (?# String options)
    |                                  (?# OR other)
    (?<options_complex>.*)
  )                                    (?# Options group end) 
  |                                    (?# OR simple structures)
  (?<simple_parameter_set>(?:(?&parameter_set)+)) (?# <----------- WRONG!!!)
\) (?# Expression end)
```

Test strings:

DOESN'T WORK:

```
or_x(equal([attr1], 1), in_array(explode([keywords]), "hello")) // There should be 2 matches: [attr1] and [keywords]
```

WORK WELL:

```
explode([Rooms])
implode(([attr1],[attr2]), ",")
implode(([attr1],[attr2]))
equal([attr1],[attr2])
implode(([attr1],[attr2]), {"sensitive":true,"nullable":false})
```

It works well, except the last rule - it captures only the last occurrence. I tried recursion with `(?R)`, but it fails with an endless loop.

So the problem I believe only in that line I marked as `WRONG`. The rest captures all other test strings w/o any problems.

I expect to have `[attr1]` and `[keywords]` matched.

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/eDjZhP/8).

**UPD 1.** I use `preg_replace_callback` to substitute real values, so all I do it here is just fetching `[somevar]` data to an array (and doing some other captures) and replacing it with what I need. See below.

**UPD 2.**

**Case 1:**

`or_x(equal([attr1], 1), in_array(explode([keywords]), "hello"))`

will be transformed to

`or_x(equal($attr1, 1), in_array(explode($keywords), "hello"))`

**Case 2:**

`implode(([attr1],[attr2]), ",")`

will be transformed to

`implode([$attr1,$attr2], ",")`

**Case 3:**

`implode(([attr1],[attr2]), {"sensitive":true,"nullable":false})`

will be transformed to

`implode([$attr1,$attr2], '{"sensitive":true,"nullable":false}')`

**UPD 3.**

**Rules:**

- every expression is a function call, which contains Function name, parentheses, at least one parameter and optional Function flags:
- `func([param])` - one parameter
- `func([param1], [param1])` - two parameters, space between params is ignored.
- `func(([param1], [param1]), "some_flag")` - if the flag is specified, then parameter set should be enclosed into additional parentheses.
- `func(([param1], [param1]), {"flag1": true, "flag2": "test", "flag2": 123})` - flags may be specified as JSON.
- all matches of `[pattern]` should become $pattern
- `func(([param1], func([param1])` - any level of nesting is supported
- `func(([param1], func(([param1], [param1]), "some_flag")` - nesting is supported with support of all rules above

Comment: Should we find out what right match is?

Comment: What do you mean? I've specified what result I expect. Duplicated below one more time.

Comment: That was for made to be explicit. But removed & updated.

Comment: `, 1)` has no matching pattern in your regular expression. So first bracket would not match.

Comment: @revo but I'm trying to match the named expression which is bound to `parameter_set` and then I'm referring to it in my "WRONG" line. So I don't need `, 1)` to match.

Comment: `parameter_set` matches a mandatory closing bracket `]` then a closing parenthesis `)`. After `[attr1]` there is a sequence of comma, space and a digit and finally a `)`. You missed every thing in between.

Comment: For example what if arguments were `1, [attr1]`?

Comment: Ahh yeah... I didn't predict it..

Comment: I believe it should be done with look behind somehow, but not yet sure how to do it. Still playing with it.

Comment: Actually I don't care about `1`, I care about `[attr1]` only. I use `preg_replace_callback` to substitute real values.

Comment: It's better to talk about your requirements in your question so others can be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: Makes sense. Added my use cases

Comment: In adding requirements you should be clear which substrings under which conditions should be matched and what are false-positives that should be excluded from match. By current *from -> to* syntax we can't read your mind and understand rules behind it. It's Regular Expression that seeks for rules.

Comment: Sure thing. Added rules. I had to do all these things initially, sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for down voting w/o a comment.

Comment: @SerhiiMatrunchyk: I think you are looking for something like this: https://3v4l.org/h0UitB . Note that it needs a precise description of all possible kind of tokens and also several passes to deal with elements that are not at the same nesting level.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte please make it as answer. It works just great!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm trying to decompile your Regexp :) What if it should also match `[attr1]` w/o an operator? What definition should I change then?

Comment: @SerhiiMatrunchyk: What do you mean by *"w/o an operator"*?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Handles incorrectly `get($attr1, '{"map":{"a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3}}')`, adding quotes around nested JSON